# Aruch ha-Shulchan he-Atid online

Tags: jewish-books, aruch-hashulchan

Is the entire *Aruch ha-Shulchan he-Atid* available online anywhere?

There are some volumes on Otzar but they definitely aren't the whole thing. For instance [the final volume included](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/pages/?&restore=1&t=1606323339874&pagenum=3&book=155083) covers the laws of nazirut and monetary evaluations, but [Wikisource](https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%94%D7%A2%D7%AA%D7%99%D7%93_%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%95%D7%98%D7%99%D7%9D) states that the contents should include these two topics but also many others (eg Sanhedrin, kings etc). Similarly, the [coverage of Zeraim](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/pages/?&restore=1&t=1606323930795&pagenum=144&book=13611) only includes the start of this section.

So, can anyone point me to a complete online edition of the remainder of *Aruch ha-Shulchan he-Atid*?

Many thanks.

Comment: The table of contents goes up to page 171, but there are 336 pages in the book. Maybe the topics you're looking for are already included with a separate table of contents in the middle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Bar Ilan](https://www.responsa.co.il) seems to have it, under ספרי הלכה ומנהג/ספרי הלכה ומנהג - אחרונים/ערוך השלחן העתיד.  I'm not familiar with the structure, but the table of contents includes Sanhedrin and kings, at least, under הלכות שונות.